# HTML tags in a block body are not rendred

Tags: blocks, installation-profiles

I'm using Drupal 8. I have created a custom installation profile. Inside the profile profileName.install file, I created the following function:

```
function setupCustomBlocks() {
  $blockContent = BlockContent::create([
        'type' => 'basic',
        'info' => 'Why choose us?',
  ]);
  $blockContent->set('body', '<p><i class="fa fa-drupal">&nbsp;</i></p>
                              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>'
  );
  $blockContent->save();

  $block = Block::create([
        'id' => 'why_choose_us',
        'plugin' => 'block_content:' . $blockContent->uuid(),
        'region' => 'topwidget_first',
        'provider' => 'block_content',
        'weight' => 0,
        'theme' => \Drupal::config('system.theme')->get('default'),
        'visibility' => array(),
        'settings' => [
          'label' => 'Why choose us?',
          'label_display' => TRUE,
        ],
  ]);
  $block->save();
}
```

The bellow function, allows me to create a custom block when I install the profile. Here is the result:

[image]

As you can see, the HTML tags are not rendering. How can fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's rendering the block's content a plain text, not HTML, because you aren't setting the body field's format property when creating the `BlockContent` entity.

```
$blockContent = \Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent::create([ 'type' => 'basic', 'info' => 'Why choose us?' ]);
$blockContent->body->value = '<p><i class="fa fa-drupal">&nbsp;</i></p>
                              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>';
$blockContent->body->format = 'full_html';
$blockContent->save();
```